# Wysiwyg editor with filemanager for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wysiwyg

please, do you know any good wysiwyg editor for asp.net? With filemanager? I can't find any free.

For website in PHP there are so many opportunities. But nothing for asp.net :-(

Thanks for answers.

Comment: I used to have the same problem and I had solved it by writing my own plugin for TinyMCE (the best choice I think). It was very easy, about 2 hours.

Comment: I can help you with the code if you decide to go this way...

Comment: Thank you, but I am the beginner, so I prefer plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio Express is your best tool - it is free and very robust can be [downloaded here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

Or if you are using Rich Text Editor to host in the browser you can start with 
control from  [Rich Text Editor for ASP.NET and MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RichTextEditor/) on NuGet

Comment: I think OP is looking for something to run in the browser on his site, not a code editor.

Comment: got it. thank you. Then maybe Nuget will help https://www.nuget.org/packages/RichTextEditor/

Comment: Thanks, but Rich Text Editor on NuGet isnt free ($149 per domain).